# How do I loop through 3 card fragments in a grid pager adapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, wear-os, android-pageradapter

I am trying to loop through 3 card fragments in grid pager adapter. My grid pager adapter code is here:

```
/**
 * Constructs fragments as requested by the GridViewPager. For each row a different background is
 * provided.
 * <p>
 * Always avoid loading resources from the main thread. In this sample,the background images are
 * loaded from an background task and then updated using {@link #notifyRowBackgroundChanged(int)}
 * and {@link #notifyPageBackgroundChanged(int, int)}.
 */
public class SampleGridPagerAdapter extends FragmentGridPagerAdapter {
private static final int TRANSITION_DURATION_MILLIS = 100;

private final Context mContext;
private List<Row> mRows;
private ColorDrawable mDefaultBg;

private ColorDrawable mClearBg;

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
public SampleGridPagerAdapter(Context ctx, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = ctx;

    mRows = new ArrayList<Row>();

    mRows.add(new Row(cardFragment(R.string.welcome_title, R.string.welcome_text),
            cardFragment(R.string.about_title, R.string.about_text),
            cardFragment(R.string.cards_title, R.string.cards_text),
            cardFragment(R.string.expansion_title, R.string.expansion_text)));

    mDefaultBg = new ColorDrawable(R.color.dark_grey);
    mClearBg = new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
}

LruCache<Integer, Drawable> mRowBackgrounds = new LruCache<Integer, Drawable>(3) {
    @Override
    protected Drawable create(final Integer row) {
        int resid = BG_IMAGES[row % BG_IMAGES.length];
        new DrawableLoadingTask(mContext) {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
                TransitionDrawable background = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {
                        mDefaultBg,
                        result
                });
                mRowBackgrounds.put(row, background);
                notifyRowBackgroundChanged(row);
                background.startTransition(TRANSITION_DURATION_MILLIS);
            }
        }.execute(resid);
        return mDefaultBg;
    }
};

LruCache<Point, Drawable> mPageBackgrounds = new LruCache<Point, Drawable>(3) {
    @Override
    protected Drawable create(final Point page) {
        // place bugdroid as the background at row 2, column 1
        if (page.y == 2 && page.x == 1) {
            int resid = R.drawable.bugdroid_large;
            new DrawableLoadingTask(mContext) {
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
                    TransitionDrawable background = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {
                            mClearBg,
                            result
                    });
                    mPageBackgrounds.put(page, background);
                    notifyPageBackgroundChanged(page.y, page.x);
                    background.startTransition(TRANSITION_DURATION_MILLIS);
                }
            }.execute(resid);
        }
        return GridPagerAdapter.BACKGROUND_NONE;
    }
};

private Fragment cardFragment(int titleRes, int textRes) {
    Resources res = mContext.getResources();
    CardFragment fragment =
            CardFragment.create(res.getText(titleRes), res.getText(textRes));
    // Add some extra bottom margin to leave room for the page indicator
    fragment.setCardMarginBottom(
            res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.card_margin_bottom));
    return fragment;
}

static final int[] BG_IMAGES = new int[] {
        R.drawable.debug_background_1,
        R.drawable.debug_background_2,
        R.drawable.debug_background_3,
        R.drawable.debug_background_4,
        R.drawable.debug_background_5
};

/** A convenient container for a row of fragments. */
private class Row {
    final List<Fragment> columns = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public Row(Fragment... fragments) {
        for (Fragment f : fragments) {
            add(f);
        }
    }

    public void add(Fragment f) {
        columns.add(f);
    }

    Fragment getColumn(int i) {
        return columns.get(i);
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.size();
    }
}

@Override
public Fragment getFragment(int row, int col) {
    Row adapterRow = mRows.get(row);
    return adapterRow.getColumn(col);
}

@Override
public Drawable getBackgroundForRow(final int row) {
    return mRowBackgrounds.get(row);
}

@Override
public Drawable getBackgroundForPage(final int row, final int column) {
    return mPageBackgrounds.get(new Point(column, row));
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return mRows.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount(int rowNum) {
    return mRows.get(rowNum).getColumnCount();
}

class DrawableLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Drawable> {
    private static final String TAG = "Loader";
    private Context context;

    DrawableLoadingTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading asset 0x" + Integer.toHexString(params[0]));
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(params[0]);
    }
}
}
```

I started from the google developer example code found here : https://developer.android.com/samples/GridViewPager/project.html and modified it to be one row of card fragments. Is there any way to repeatedly loop through them?

Comment: Why do you want to loop tru these cards? To update data?

Comment: The idea is to take them through instructions for 3 activities. These activities are repeated until they are performed correctly. It may mean we need to go through the activities once, twice, or even 12 times. Once the activities are performed correctly, we would like to move on to a "You did it!" card.